# What does a "\" in a string mean?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

What does a "\" in a string mean?

For example:

```
>>> "\033"
```

The output is:

```
'\x1b'
```

If you try to print the string, the result is an odd-looking square

Most weridly, if you enter this into your shell:

```
>>> "\033" == "\x1b"
```

The output is:

```
True
```

Obviously, Python thinks of the "\" as a special character, but how does it work?

Comment: A string in source code is called a literal string (or string literal). If it was in a string value, it would just be data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a character represented by the octal number `033`.
In decimal, that number is `27`.
In hex, that number is `0x1b`.

See [the escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) used by Python.

---

> But if you print it, you get a small square. Any explanations?

It's most likely that your platform uses ASCII encoding. In ASCII encoding, the number 27 represents the `ESC` character. It is not a printable character. Your terminal prints a small square for it. Other terminals are likely to print a different symbol for it.

Comment: But if you print it, you get a small square. Any explanations?

Comment: the explanation is that the value does not represent a printable character

Comment: Ohh... if you enter "\400" into the shell, you get an 'A' with a line on it. Does that mean it's a printable character? I googled for the Unicode number of the werid "A". The code for it is "0100", or in Python, "\u0100". Are these two numbers somehow related?

Comment: Ohh... I see. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

That is a string escape.  They have quite a few uses, and they are detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).  In particular you are seeing Octal and Hexadecimal representation of byte values.

> \ooo  Character with octal value ooo  (1,3)
>
> \xhh  Character with hex value hh (2,3)

Answer (score 1):

```
\033
```

is the octal code for <kbd>esc</kbd> and

```
\x1b
```

is the same in hex

Check `man ascii`

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is an escape character. For example, if you want to print a string with quotes in it, you would need to escape the quotes inside the string so that they don't end the string.

for example:

```
print('the \'single quotes\' in this string are escaped!')
```